# Racket struct error: given value instantiates a different structure type with the same name

Tags: struct, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm pretty familiar with Racket, and many in the Scheme and Lisp family, but I have no idea what is up with this error, or what is causing it:

```
network-biases: contract violation;
 given value instantiates a different structure type with the same name
  expected: network?
  given: (network ...) <-- I omitted this because its useless.
```

Heres the function where the error is (I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/christopherdumas/e9b3b1fe416c4dc54805) of the rest):

```
(define (update-mini-batch net mini-batch eta)
  (define nabla-b (map (lambda (b)
             (apply grid (shape b))) (network-biases net)))
  (define nabla-w (map (lambda (w)
             (apply grid (shape w))) (network-weights net)))

  (define-values (nabla-b-new nabla-w-new)
    (foldl (lambda (lst bw)
       (define x (first lst))
       (define y (second lst))
       (define-values (nabla-b nabla-w) bw)
       (define-values (delta-nabla-b delta-nabla-w) (backprop net x y))

       (define nabla-b-new (+/ nabla-b delta-nabla-b))
       (define nabla-w-new (+/ nabla-w delta-nabla-w))
       (values nabla-b-new nabla-w-new)) (values nabla-b nabla-w) mini-batch))

  (struct-copy network net
           [biases (map (lambda (b nb)
                  (- b (* nb (/ eta (length mini-batch)))))
                (network-biases net) nabla-b-new)]
           [weights (map (lambda (w nw)
                   (- w (* nw (/ eta (length mini-batch)))))
                 (network-weights net) nabla-w-new)]))
```

I couldn't get an MCVE that actually threw an error, so I don't have one to give.

The distilled basics of what I'm trying to do in the above function is this:

- Calculate new values for a structure's properties, and create a new structure with those new properties.

- Thanks!!

Comment: The gist doesn't show the example that provokes the error.

Comment: Oops! OK, Ill change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures in Racket are generative. This means that each time

```
(struct network (num-layers sizes biases weights) #:transparent)
```

is run, a new type of structure is created. These are all named network.

The error message you see is usually due to evaluating the structure definition twice (and it is a bit confusing since the two types have the same name).

I can't see anywhere in your code that could lead to `(struct network ...)` being run twice. Are you using DrRacket or an alternative environment that doesn't reset namespace?

If I open "nn.rkt" and run it, will I see the error?

Comment: No, I have to run the `SGD` function to get the error. If this helps, I'm in Emacs 24 on Mac OS X, using Gieser.

Comment: You need an array like: `'((((1) (1)) ((0))) (((1) (0)) ((1))) (((0) (1)) ((1))) (((0) (0)) ((1))))`. In fact, thats the one I'm using. Then run this command: `(SGD network td 30 2 3.0 td)`, which is the exact command I'm using. Then your good! (BTW, `td` is the array. Like: `(define td ...)`)

Comment: Just use: `(build-network '(2 3 1))`. Thanks, by the way!

Comment: This `(let ([td '((((1) (1)) ((0))) (((1) (0)) ((1))) (((0) (1)) ((1))) (((0) (0)) ((1))))])
    (SGD (build-network '(2 3 1)) td 30 2 3.0 td))` gives me an error in `update-mini-batch`.

Comment: Can you make a gist that when run directly gives the error.

Comment: Sure! [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/christopherdumas/e9b3b1fe416c4dc54805#file-make-error-now-rkt).

Comment: If you're asking for an MCVE, than like I said in the question, I'm at a loss as to how to get one. I tried, but none of them actually throw an error.

Comment: Okay - if I put your three files together I get this https://gist.github.com/soegaard/82fa4b71c2c377fe9872  which gives an error in `update-mini-batch`.   Can you check that you also get that error?

Comment: I am just looking for an example that can reproduce the error. It doesn't need to be minimal.

Comment: That was the error I got, but wait! Now I'm getting an error with the shape function. I'll fix that and update the gist. Go ahead and check my gist again.

Comment: Wow, this is weird, Im getting a lot of the different errors, but not the original one! Hold on, let me bang these out....

Comment: @ChristopherDumas Great to hear. Now what was the cause? I think it was an inconsistent state in Geiser. DrRacket will reset the state each time the program is run. If the state isn't reset - and the declaration `(struct network ...)` is run twice you will get the behaviour you saw.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was just an issue with geiser!